# Processing log file entries with double-quotes on the timestamp

Tags: bash, date, awk, timestamp, quotes

I have a CSV log file for which each record has double-quotes around the timestamp, in the following form:

```
"2018-10-22 14:38:29", ...comma-separated values...
"2018-10-22 13:18:07", ...comma-separated values...
```

I want to extract records based on the timestamp, and to adjust this timestamp programmatically using `date`, but I am not having much luck doing this due to the double-quotes.

I can make it work when I hard-code the timestamp in my script...

```
# This will work
awk ' 
    BEGIN { FS=" "; split_stamp="\"2018-10-22 14:00:00\"" }
    $1<=split_stamp { print $0 )
' $filename
```

but not when assign the target timestamp to a separate variable (which I would preferably set via a command line option)...

```
# But this fails silently
split_at="\"2018-10-22 00:00:00\""
awk ' 
    BEGIN { FS=" "; split_stamp=$split_at }
    $1<=split_stamp { print $0 )
' $filename
```

Any suggestions on how to handle the double-quotes (without having to make a separate copy of the log file with the double quotes removed)?  Or perhaps there is a better tool available than `awk`?

Comment: There are two solutions. Write your own bash parser, and remember to handle `" esacped doubleqoutes \" "` correctly. Or just use [csvtool](https://colin.maudry.com/csvtool-manual-page/).

Answer (score 0):

A solution using csvtool:

```
printf "%s\n" '"2018-11-22 13:18:07",aaa' '"2018-09-21 14:38:29",bbb' > input.csv
split_at_ts=$(date --date="2018-10-22 00:00:00" +%s);
func() { 
    declare -g split_at_ts
    local ts
    ts=$(date --date="$1" +%s)
    if ((ts < split_at_ts)); then 
        printf "%s" "$*"
    fi
}
export -f func
export split_at_ts
csvtool call f input.csv
```

csvtool will call funtion f for each line in csv file with arguments equal to fields in that csvfile.
To compare two dates I need to convert them into seconds since epoch and then I compare numbers. If date is earlier then split_at I print it from inside the function func.